# How to combine two cmp conditions in `Ord::cmp()`

Tags: rust

I'm trying to combine more than one condition when implementing `cmp()` and `eq()` from `Ord` and `PartialEq` traits. Something that looks like this:

```
self.id.cmp(&other.id) && self.age.cmp(&other.age)
```

Here's a working example minus the combined condition:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Eq)]
pub struct Person {
    pub id: u32,
    pub age: u32,
}

impl Person {
    pub fn new(id: u32, age: u32) -> Self {
        Self {
            id,
            age,
        }
    }
}

impl Ord for Person {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.id.cmp(&other.id)
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for Person {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl PartialEq for Person {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.id == other.id
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Ord` doesn't return a boolean, it returns an [`Ordering`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/enum.Ordering.html) which can be Less, Equal or Greater, so you can't just use `&&` on it.

`Ordering` has a few methods, one of which is [`then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/enum.Ordering.html#method.then) (and its companion [`then_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/enum.Ordering.html#method.then_with)), which does the usual "sort by one field, and then by another one" operation. Your example then becomes

```rust
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.id.cmp(&other.id)
            .then(self.age.cmp(&other.age))
    }
```

Comment: That's actually nice!

Comment: Thanks! In fact, [`Enum std::cmp::Ordering`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/enum.Ordering.html) seems to have many useful methods.